# MySQL: How do I retrieve a record that meets circumstantial criteria?

Tags: mysql

Let me start with, I am extremely new to SQL and I've been trying to figure this problem out for most of the week now. The database I'm pulling from is in phpmyadmin. What I have is a form, with several records, that I need to know which ones meet certain criteria. Specifically, I need to know which ones are Pending Approval and have been signed off on so I can mark them as Approved.

There are 11 different Signature Request fields (for different departments) that each have their own Signature field. I need to know which records have Signature Request fields marked as 'Approval' (meaning a signature is required from that department) and have a signature in the Signature field. On top of that, I also need it to only return records that are Pending Approval.

Basically the table looks like this:

```
+----+------------+--------+------------+--------+------------+--------+----------------+
| id | sign_rqst1 | sign1  | sign_rqst2 | sign2  | sign_rqst3 | sign3  |status          |
+----+------------+--------+------------+--------+------------+--------+----------------+
|  1 | Approval   | [sign] |            |        | Approval   | [sign] |Pending Approval|
|  2 |            |        | Approval   | [sign] | Approval   |        |Pending Approval|
|  3 | Approval   |        | Notice     |        |            |        |Pending Approval|
|  4 | Approval   | [sign] | Approval   | [sign] |            |        |Approved        |
+----+------------+--------+------------+--------+------------+--------+----------------+
```

I need my query to return `1` and ignore `2, 3 & 4`. But I can't figure out how to write the query to ignore records that don't fit the criteria. The `AND` and `OR` operators don't seem to be helping me in this scenario.

I've tried:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE sign_rqst1 IN ('Approval') AND sign1'' AND status = 'Pending Approval' AND

SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE sign_rqst2 IN ('Approval') AND sign2'' AND status = 'Pending Approval' AND

SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE sign_rqst3 IN ('Approval') AND sign3'' AND status = 'Pending Approval' AND

GROUP BY id;
```

This returns nothing, and `OR` returns everything.

Then I tried this (just using one set of columns to see if it would even work):

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE sign_rqst1 IN ('Approval') AND status = 'Pending Approval'
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sign1'');
```

And it didn't parse out the ones that had no signature, so I got every record that had `Approval` marked in `sign_rqst1`.

I also tried a Temporary Table, but I couldn't even get that query to work.

I'm thinking I need to search for all the Approvals first, then use that to search for the Approvals that have signatures, but I have no idea how to do that and I haven't been able to find anything that helps. Any ideas?

EDIT: I should add that the signatures are actually image files. The program we use has a Signature Authority button that is replaced by a Signature image file when someone signs, so in the table it shows up as `so-and-so.png` so using `<>''` to grab the fields that just have something in them is the only way I could figure out how to handle this mess.

```
CREATE TABLE `qms_engineering_change_order` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eng_action` text,
  `eng_signature` text,
  `eng_action2` text NOT NULL,
  `eng_signature2` text NOT NULL,
  `eng_signature3` text NOT NULL,
  `eng_action3` text NOT NULL,
  `eng_action4` text NOT NULL,
  `eng_signature4` text NOT NULL,
  `plan_action` text,
  `plan_signature` text,
  `sc_action` text,
  `sc_signature` text,
  `qa_action` text,
  `qa_signature` text,
  `oth_action` text,
  `oth_signature` text,
  `dcc_signature` text,
  `dcc_signature` text,
  `prod_signature` text,
  `prod_action` text,
  `sales_action` text,
  `sales_signature` text,
```

Comment: Your data structure violates [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).  You *really* should consider instead having `(id, status)` in one table and `(id, num, sign_rqst, sign)` in another.

Comment: The program we use, which uses phpmyadmin for all the tables, is pretty rudimentary, so I'm stuck trying to make things work until I can convince the bosses that we need something better.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, phpMyAdmin is not a database; it's an administrative interface which people can use to manage their MySQL database instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my theory of creating a `Temporary Table` was the way to go, it just took me a while to figure out how to use the table to my advantage. I created the table to only show all of the `Approval` actions and their `Signatures`, compiled under two columns instead of 22.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE NeedApproval AS (
SELECT id, sign_rqst1 'ActionRequired', COALESCE(sign1) 'Signature'
FROM table
WHERE sign_rqst1 IN ('Approval') AND status = 'Pending Approval');

INSERT INTO NeedApproval
SELECT id, sign_rqst2 'ActionRequired', COALESCE(sign2) 'Signature'
FROM table
WHERE sign_rqst2 IN ('Approval') AND status = 'Pending Approval';

INSERT INTO NeedApproval
SELECT id, sign_rqst3 'ActionRequired', COALESCE(sign3) 'Signature'
FROM table
WHERE sign_rqst3 IN ('Approval') AND status = 'Pending Approval';
```

etc.. to include all of the fields. With my table looking more like this:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id | sign_rqst1 | sign1  | 
|  1 | Approval   | [sign] | 
|  1 | Approval   | [sign] | 
|  2 | Approval   | [sign] | 
|  2 | Approval   |        | 
|  3 | Approval   |        |  
+----+------------+--------+
```

Then I used a `COUNT` function (a more specific version of the one I'd tried before) to give me all of the records where all of the `Approval` actions had `Signatures`. This is the query I used on the `Temporary Table`:

```
SELECT id
FROM NeedApproval
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN signature<>'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

The database only has 166 records, so I was able to go through and manually check to see that it did what I needed. This worked perfectly, even if it took a little longer to work up than I'd anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the problem is in the way you're writing your query. Try using a query like this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE status = 'Pending Approval' AND (
    sign_rqst1='Approval' AND sign1<>'' OR
    sign_rqst2='Approval' AND sign2<>'' OR
    sign_rqst3='Approval' AND sign3<>'');
```

Comment: This does the same as my first attempt using the OR operation. Just returns all the records that have the sign_rqst fields marked for Approval, regardless of if their sign fields have a signature or not. I just want the ones that do have a signature.

Answer (score 0):

[udpated to handle nulls]

Try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE status = 'Pending Approval' AND
(
    ((ifnull(sign_rqst1,'') = 'Approval' AND ifnull(sign1,'')<>'') OR ifnull(sign_rqst1,'') = '') AND
    ((ifnull(sign_rqst2,'') = 'Approval' AND ifnull(sign2,'')<>'') OR ifnull(sign_rqst2,'') = '') AND
    . . .
    ((ifnull(sign_rqst11,'') = 'Approval' AND ifnull(sign11,'')<>'') OR ifnull(sign_rqst11,'') = '')
)
```

`ifnull(expr1, expr2)` returns `expr1` if it is not null, otherwise it returns `expr2`.  This way I ensure that null strings are handled as empty strings: `''` not `NULL`.

Comment: Unfortunately, with what I have to work with, I can't use this part of the code sign1 = '[sign]'   The signature field is filled with an image of a signature and for a few of the fields the person signing differs. I did try it though, with sign1<>'' instead, and it returned some records that didn't have any of the sign_rqst fields marked 'Approval' and some that did.

Comment: @grymmlock: I'm wondering if null handling is causing part of your problem.  Could you post the data structure of your table.  I.e. to the sing_rqst1 and sign1 type fields allow NULLs?

Comment: Some of the fields allow NULLs and some don't. The majority of them allow NULLs. Let me reiterate, I am really new to all this, my company just kind of dropped all of this in my lap and said "learn it", without any actual support to do so. So, if there's anything you need to know, be specific and I'll do my best to find the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer to incorporate null handling.  Let me know if that helps.  Could you also post result of a `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name`,  replacing table_name as appropriate.

Comment: It still returned nothing when executed. I edited the original post to add the result you requested at the bottom. Thanks for trying to figure this out, I'm still working on it on my end as well.